# how can I do clustering with autoencoder on a numerical dataset?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I have a dataset of 17 features. I would like to cluster the data and get the labels. How can achieve that using the autoencoder with keras?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:
Start by using [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) and or [NMF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html) on your data.

After decomposition you can use [Kmeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) for clustering.

Perhaps these tools can work for your problem. If they do not, reformulate the question and elaborate on why not and the community can try to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know whether autoencoder can do clustering as Kmeans do. Like to cluster data and generate labels.

Comment: An autoencoder generates a reduced representation of an object; this representation can then be used to run a clustering algorithm such as KMeans. Although one can also run KMeans without dimensionality reduction, the results are often better if dimensionality reduction is performed. Auto-encoders are complementary to clustering rather than a replacement.